# How to create join entries in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to write associated entries to a join table, when I create or update an entry. I have Cultivars, that have and belong to many Months through HarvestingMonths, PlantingMonths, and so on. When I use the following code in the Cultivar update function

```
const updatedCultivar = await Cultivar.findByPk(id);
if (harvestingMonths && harvestingMonths.length > 0) {
  const associatedMonths = await Month.findAll({
      where: { id: harvestingMonths },
  });

  await updatedCultivar.setHarvestingMonths(associatedMonths);
}
```

I get the following response logged out:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `cultivar_id`, `month_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` FROM `harvesting_months` AS `HarvestingMonth` WHERE `HarvestingMonth`.`cultivar_id` = 2;
Executing (default): UPDATE `harvesting_months` SET `cultivar_id`=?,`updated_at`=? WHERE `id` IN ('[object SequelizeInstance:Month]', '[object SequelizeInstance:Month]')
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '[object SequelizeInstance:Month]'
```

I expected the `set<Association>` to automatically create or destroy association entries on the join table and populate them with `cultivar_id: updatedCultivar.id` and `month_id: associatedMonth.id`.

When I use

```
await updatedCultivar.setHarvestingMonths(associatedMonths.map(month => month.id));
```

It overwrites existing join entries for cultivars with other cultivar_ids. Practically for month_ids: 1 and 2 it overwrites cultivar_id in harvesting_months.id 1 and 2.

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `cultivar_id`, `month_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` FROM `harvesting_months` AS `HarvestingMonth` WHERE `HarvestingMonth`.`cultivar_id` = 2;
Executing (default): UPDATE `harvesting_months` SET `cultivar_id`=?,`updated_at`=? WHERE `id` IN (1, 2)
```

For now I wrote custom HarvestingMonth.create and destroy functionality, but that does not leverage the setAssociation Sequelize function.

When I try to run:

```
    // Remove existing harvesting months
    for (const month of sowInsideMonthsToRemove) {
        console.log("MONTH", month)
        console.log("ID", month.id)
        await updatedCultivar.removeSowInsideMonth(month);
    }
```

I get `Column 'cultivar_id' cannot be null`:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `cultivar_id`, `month_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` FROM `sow_inside_months` AS `SowInsideMonth` WHERE `SowInsideMonth`.`cultivar_id` = 2;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `sow_inside_months` (`id`,`cultivar_id`,`month_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?);
MONTH SowInsideMonth {
  dataValues: {
    id: 29,
    cultivar_id: 2,
    month_id: 1,
    created_at: 2023-05-16T05:35:30.000Z,
    updated_at: 2023-05-16T05:35:30.000Z
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    id: 29,
    cultivar_id: 2,
    month_id: 1,
    created_at: 2023-05-16T05:35:30.000Z,
    updated_at: 2023-05-16T05:35:30.000Z
  },
  uniqno: 1,
  _changed: Set(0) {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    raw: true,
    attributes: [ 'id', 'cultivar_id', 'month_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at' ]
  },
  isNewRecord: false
}
ID 29
Executing (default): UPDATE `sow_inside_months` SET `cultivar_id`=?,`updated_at`=? WHERE `cultivar_id` = ? AND `id` IN (29)
Column 'cultivar_id' cannot be null
```

What am I missing?